# UIScrollView returns error on pinch on iOS7

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm using a **UIScrollView** to scale an image:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {        
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.inputImage.frame.size
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    inputImage.image = inputImageDelegate

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.inputImage
}
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(scrollView: UIScrollView, withView view: UIView!, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    //code
}
```

This code works fine in **iOS8** but in **iOS7** I get this error:

> 2015-06-18 12:42:20.702 tahrir[96725:607] Unable to simultaneously
>   satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the
>   code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you
>   don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger. The
>   methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView
>   listed in  may also be helpful. done

**Note**: I'm using auto layout, and it has no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing auto-layout constrains fixed the problem.